# Using free on the data that I malloc'd is not working

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

At the beginning of my program I created this struct:

```
struct directive {
    char gate[17];
    int n;
    int s;
    int *inputs;
    int *outputs;
    int *selectors;
};
```

Included here is my whole main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc - 1 != 1) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //get file, return if invalid path
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //make temp of circuit with struct directive
    int scount = 0;
    struct directive* temp = NULL;
    int size = 2;
    int icount = 0;
    int ocount = 0;
    int tcount = 0;
    char dir[17];
    char **names;
    int *values;

    //get INPUT info
    fscanf(file, " %s", dir);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &icount);

    size += icount;
    names = malloc(size * sizeof(char *));
    names[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));     //MALLOC
    strcpy(names[0], "0");
    names[1] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));     //MALLOC
    strcpy(names[1], "1");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
        names[i + 2] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
        fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", names[i + 2]);
    }

    //get OUTPUT info
    fscanf(file, " %s", dir);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &ocount);
    size += ocount;
    names = realloc(names, size * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < ocount; i++) {
        names[i + icount + 2] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
        fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", names[i + icount + 2]);
    }

    //get temp
    struct directive step;
    while (!feof(file)) {
        int numInputs = 2, numOutputs = 1;

        int sc = fscanf(file, " %s", dir);
        if (sc != 1) {
            break;
        }
        scount++;
        step.n = 0;
        step.s = 0;
        strcpy(step.gate, dir);

        if (strcmp(dir, "NOT") == 0) {
            numInputs = 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(dir, "PASS") == 0) {
            numInputs = 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(dir, "DECODER") == 0) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &numInputs);
            step.n = numInputs;
            numOutputs = pow(2, numInputs);
        }
        if (strcmp(dir, "MULTIPLEXER") == 0) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &numInputs);
            step.s = numInputs;
            numInputs = pow(2, numInputs);
        }

        step.inputs = malloc(numInputs * sizeof(int));
        step.outputs = malloc(numOutputs * sizeof(int));
        step.selectors = malloc(step.s * sizeof(int));

        char v[17];
        for (i = 0; i < numInputs; i++) {
            fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", v);
            step.inputs[i] = indexOf(size, names, v);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < step.s; i++) {
            fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", v);
            step.selectors[i] = indexOf(size, names, v);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < numOutputs; i++) {
            fscanf(file, "%*[: ]%16s", v);
            int idx = indexOf(size, names, v);
            if (idx == -1) {
                size++;
                tcount++;
                names = realloc(names, size * sizeof(char *));
                names[size - 1] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(names[size - 1], v);
                step.outputs[i] = size - 1;
            }
            else {
                step.outputs[i] = idx;
            }
        }

        //add step to list of temp
        if (!temp) {
            temp = malloc(sizeof(struct directive));
        } else {
            temp = realloc(temp, scount * sizeof(struct directive));
        }
        temp[scount - 1] = step;


    }

    // initialize values array
    values = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    resetValues(size, values);

    while(1 < 2) {
        //print inputs
        for (i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
            printf("%d ", values[i + 2]);
        }
        printf("|");

        //run through temp, calculate outputs
        for (i = 0; i < scount; i++) {
            struct directive step = temp[i];
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "NOT") == 0) {
                NOT(values, step.inputs[0], step.outputs[0]);
            }
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "AND") == 0) {
                AND(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
            }
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "OR") == 0) {
                OR(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
            }
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "NAND") == 0) {
                NAND(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
            }
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "NOR") == 0) {
                NOR(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
            }
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "XOR") == 0) {
                XOR(values, step.inputs[0], step.inputs[1], step.outputs[0]);
            }
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "PASS") == 0) {
                PASS(values, step.inputs[0], step.outputs[0]);
            }
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "DECODER") == 0) {
                DECODER(values, step.n, step.inputs, step.outputs);
            }
            if (strcmp(step.gate, "MULTIPLEXER") == 0) {
                MUX(values, step.s, step.inputs, step.selectors, step.outputs[0]);
            }

        }

        //print outputs
        for (i = 0; i < ocount; i++) {
            printf(" %d", values[icount + i + 2]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        if (!incrementInputs(values, icount)) {
            break;
        }

    }


    for (i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
        free(names[i + 2]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ocount; i++) {
        free(names[i + icount + 2]);
    }

    free(step.inputs);
    free(step.outputs);
    free(step.selectors);

    free(names[0]);
    free(names[1]);

    free(values);
    free(temp);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem that I am having is when compiled, my address sanitizer is telling me that I have a memory leak at lines 203 and 204 which are these following mallocs:

```
    names = realloc(names, size * sizeof(char *));
    names[size - 1] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
```

You can see that I freed the three lines that I had allocated for, so what could be the reason that it isn't actually freeing? Do I have to loop through something and use free because of something else I did after in main?

Answer (score 0):

You allocate memory in a loop but only free what you obtained in the last iteration:

```
   ...
   while (!feof(file)) {
       ...
       step.inputs = malloc(numInputs * sizeof(int));
       step.outputs = malloc(numOutputs * sizeof(int));
       step.selectors = malloc(step.s * sizeof(int));
       ...
   }
   ...
   free(step.inputs);
   free(step.outputs);
   free(step.selectors);
   ...
```

Comment: Just got it. Thank you so much

Comment: You already accepted Oka's answer.  The other option is to keep track of the total size of each and use `realloc()`.  That way you resize each allocation instead of creating a new per loop iteration.

Comment: It did work but after looking at it further now, I realized it is also leaking at:              
   names = realloc(names, size * sizeof(char *));
  names[size - 1] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));

Comment: Yeah, I only looked at the question you asked about.

Comment: Of course. Im going to update the question

Comment: If your original question was answered then accept it and move on.  Open a new question if you need help with something else.  See [mre].

Answer (score 0):

This group of calls is only freeing the last held values of `step`, as a result of the final iteration of the `while (!feof(file)) { ... }` loop.

```
free(step.inputs);
free(step.outputs);
free(step.selectors);
```

Every iteration, `step` is copied to an element of `temp`, so you must free the members of each element before freeing `temp`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < scount; i++) {
    free(temp[i].inputs);
    free(temp[i].outputs);
    free(temp[i].selectors);
}
```

Comment: Just got it. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the question further

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the main issues, so I won't repeat them, but I want to give a few hints to make allocation a bit safer.

When you `malloc()` and need to provide the size of data, there is nothing wrong with using `sizeof(type)`, but if you get the type wrong, just as a simple typo, you get the wrong amount of memory. Even if you don't make any mistakes, it can bite you if you change a pointer type at some later point. The compiler doesn't check if the size you give `malloc()` is correct (it can't, really), so you don't get any warning about places where you allocated size for the wrong type.

So, in allocations such as

```c
    names = malloc(size * sizeof(char *));
    names[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    names[i + 2] = malloc(17 * sizeof(char));
    step.inputs = malloc(numInputs * sizeof(int));
    step.outputs = malloc(numOutputs * sizeof(int));
    step.selectors = malloc(step.s * sizeof(int));
```

all the `sizeof()` are potential hiding places for bugs.

You can, instead, get the size from the pointer you are assigning the allocation to. Not always, of course, there are times where you need to allocate something and you don't have a variable you assign to--sending allocated memory to a function or some-such, but 99% of the time, if you malloc you are assigning to a variable. And you can get the size of the type that variable points to using `sizeof` as well. The `sizeof` operator comes in two flavours. One that takes a type, `sizeof(type)` and one that takes an expression, `sizeof expressions` or `sizeof(expression)`; the parentheses are optional here.

You can change the allocations above to this:

```c
    names = malloc(size * sizeof *names);
    names[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof *names[0])
    names[i + 2] = malloc(17 * sizeof *names[i + 2])
    step.inputs = malloc(numInputs * sizeof *step.inputs);
    step.outputs = malloc(numOutputs * sizeof *step.outputs);
    step.selectors = malloc(step.s * sizeof *step.selectors);
```

You need to dereference the variable here, because otherwise you get the size of the pointer and not what it points to, but don't worry about this dereference. The compiler is not going to emit code that actually dereferences, which in any case would be disastrous considering that the pointers are not initialised yet. No, the pointer just works out the type of the expression and gets the size from there. That way, the allocation and the type of what you want to allocate space for is kept consistent.

Another thing is the `realloc()` you do:

```c
    names = realloc(names, size * sizeof(char *));
```

It is, admittedly, unlikely to fail, but if it does, `realloc()` returns `NULL`, and if it does, it hasn't freed its input pointer. If this `realloc()` failed, you would have `NULL` in `names`, and you would have leaked the memory that `names` pointed at before.

You generally shouldn't assign the result from `realloc()` directly to the input pointer for that reason. It is better to assign to a temporary variable, check if the allocation failed, and if not, then you can assign to the variable you want to hold the result.

```c
    char **tmp = realloc(names, size * sizeof *tmp);
    if (!tmp) abort(); // handle alloc failure
    names = tmp;
```

This, of course, depends on whether you plan to handle allocation failures. I just `abort()` here, and you could do the same without assigning to a `tmp` variable

```c
    names = realloc(names, size * sizeof *tmp);
    if (!names) abort(); // handle alloc failure
```

If you are running on a desktop, allocation errors are unlikely to ever be a problem, and terminating the program with some appropriate error message is an easy fix that is probably fine.

Comment: Thank you, this a huge help. Is there anything you can tell me about the free calls then, especially for the realloc line?

Comment: realloc() will automatically free the input pointer if necessary (so after assigning to tmp you *must* assign tmp back to names if you want to avoid trouble). At the end, you must free names like any other allocated memory.

Comment: I'm not sure where to place free(names[size-1]); then

Comment: Wherever you free `names`; it has nothing to do with `realloc()`; you just need to free the pointer as if you had never invoked `realloc()`.

Comment: Hmm, I have that line with my frees but it still insists that  names[size - 1] is leaking. It might be a result of something else